# Marketing Cloud - Can I pull in data from a data extension other than the one I'm sending to?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, dataextensions

I have two data extensions.

**Data extension A** has a record for each quote created via our website in the last 24 hours. There may be multiple records per email address, if the user has elected to create multiple quotes.
**Data extension B** is created from data extension A, and captures **unique email addresses** from the last 24 hours. There is one record per email address.

I would like to send one follow-up email to the user, which includes a table containing information about all of the quotes they created in the last 24 hours. Obviously I cannot just send to data extension A, because that would send them an email for each quote record. My plan to accomplish this was creating data extension B and sending to that data extension. However, I've realized that I don't know how to code the email to reference data extension A while sending to data extension B.

Any advice for how to accomplish this task?

Comment: Look at the LookUpRows AMPScript function

Comment: Thank you. This works for my table, but how would I use this function if I only wanted to pull in one variable, like a personalization string?

Comment: You would utilize the Lookup() function for that. Please review the AMPscript functions available here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm

Comment: Is it required to know what you're looking for to use the lookup function, though? I tried using it and couldn't get it to work for my use case. For example, if I wanted to insert their first name, I wouldn't write a lookup string for each individual first name in my data extension.

Comment: you would do `Lookup(DE_A, 'FirstName', 'email_address', emailaddr)`.  This would grab the first name in Data Extension A associated with the current sendable email address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help anyone else that runs across this issue, I am turning the comments into an answer.

You would use the [LookupRows()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm) AMPScript function if you need to grab multiple values returned from a different DE

**Sample: (multiple results)**

```
%%[
   SET @Rowset = LookupRows('DEa','PrimaryKey', PrimaryKey)

   FOR @i = 1 TO ROWCOUNT(@Rowset) DO
     SET @Row = Row(@Rowset,@i)
     SET @fName = Field(@Row, 'FirstName')
     SET @lName = Field(@Row, 'LastName')

     OUTPUT(CONCAT(@fName, " ", @lName, "<br />")
     /* This will gather the First and Last Name of each row and Output it */

   NEXT @i
]%%
```

**Sample: [single result using [LookupOrderedRows()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuporderedrows.htm)]**

```
%%[
   SET @Rowset = LookupOrderedRows('DEa', 1, 'EmailAddress ASC','EmailAddress', emailaddr) 

   /* Returns only a single row meeting the WHERE criteria of EmailAddress = emailaddr 
   and ordered by Email Address Ascending */

     SET @Row = Row(@Rowset,1)
     SET @fName = Field(@Row, 'FirstName')
     SET @lName = Field(@Row, 'LastName')
     SET @otherValue = Field(@Row, 'OtherValue')

     /* Set the fields you want from the 'Row' (@Row) using the Field() function */

]%%
```

Or you would use the [Lookup()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm) AMPScript function if you only need a single value returned from a different DE.

**Sample**

`SET @fName = Lookup(DE_A, 'FirstName', 'email_address', emailaddr)
/* Will return the First Name only from a single entry*/`

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and it worked, but as you said, it only provides the results from a single entry. Is there a way to get the results from all of the applicable records, besides in a table format?

Comment: you would do the LookupRows or LookupOrderedRows(). Then use field to get it. I will add an extra example to my answer.